# How can I use row values in conjunction with columns?

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I've got a chart and I've got some numbers in the first couple columns. I want the next column, C, to have the numbers from the first two columns added together. I've tried using the ROW() attribute to do this, but I don't know how to apply it to specific columns, and it's tedious to write the column number for every time I want to do this.

Is there any way I can write a universal function that adds the two columns of a certain row together?

```
   | A | B  | C
  1|1.3|1.4 |=(this row's a column plus this row's b column)
  2|1.2|1.5 |=(this row's a column plus this row's b column)
```

Comment: Simply typing `C1 = A1+B1` and copying the formula below should do the job. The references are _relative_, meaning they will refer to the correct entries in other rows.

Answer (score 1):

In C1 and copied down to suit:

```
=sum(A1:B1)
```

[SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)

Or without copying down:

```
=ArrayFormula(A1:A+B1:B)
```